# awakeFromInsert never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an application that uses Core Data. I have two data models in the project and I create the ManagedObjectContext by merging the two models. Here the code where I do that:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL* entityURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"User_data" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel* entityModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:entityURL]; 

    NSURL* whoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"WHO_data" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel* whoModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:whoURL];

    NSArray* models = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:entityModel, whoModel, nil];
    __managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel modelByMergingModels:models];

    return __managedObjectModel; 
}
```

None of the attributes in my entities are optional and my app crashes when I try to save my managedObjectContext. I believe this is because some of the attributes are not being set. I have overridden awakeFromInsert: for the parent entity:

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    NSString* userCFUUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"device_identifier"];

    if ( userCFUUID ) {
        [self cfuuid:userCFUUID];
    } else {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Entry: awakeFromInsert: cannot find CFUUID"];
    }

    [self setCreationDate:[NSDate date]]; // the time since Jan 1st 1970 in seconds
    [self setEventDate:[NSDate date]]; 
}
```

But awakeFromInsert: is never called. I've set a breakpoint and stepped through from the statement where I create the NSManagedObject:

```
LengthEntry *length1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LengthEntry" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

Additional fact that may or may not be relavent:
After creating the datamodel containing the problem entity, I used the Xcode feature to automatically create the classes. I then realised that since I had not specified to do otherwise in the model, xcode named the classes in the plural sense (because that's what I had called them in the model). So, I ended up with "Entries.h" instead of "Entry.h". I went back and manually changed all the classes and specified in the model the name of the classes.

So, I need to figure out why awakeFromInsert is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of desperation, I deleted the datamodel and the NSManagedObject classes. I then recreated the model and the classes.

Now, it works. Something screwy must have happened when I manually changed the names of the classes.

Comment: I'm going to throw in my 2 cents, it seems typical that this happens when adding the class to the entity in the editor is forgotten.  This ensures that the custom implementation is never used, although the entity definition is enough for core data to split your hud into a object store.

Comment: @Moses, for me it was indeed forgetting to set the class for the child entity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`awakeFromInsert` is called exactly once for each object when it is first created.

What you want is `awakeFromFetch` in order to have it called every time that it is loaded into memory from the store.

Many times, you want the same or similar code in both places.